# select records with date in the last 24 hours

Tags: mysql, select

I want to select from my table all records where date (datetime mysql format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) is in the last 24 hours. I have a query, but it doesn't completely work

```
 SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

why it returns the date like that 2013-07-01 12:00:00. How would I do this? Thanks.

Comment: You're asking it to return all dates greater than 24 hours ago. July is greater than 24 hours ago.  Perhaps you're thinking of BETWEEN?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You already have a lower limit on the date, but since your table can have future dates you also need an upper limit. This should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
  AND date <= NOW()
```

Answer (score 1):

mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date >= now() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR;
```